# how to make my JAR work without -Djava.library.path parameter in Netbeans 7

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm building a JAR file which contains next argument in VM Options:

```
-Djava.library.path="\lib\win32-x86\"
```

there I have the .dll files required for making my java app work, I want my jar to run without that parameter, I modified the build.xml file by adding next code lines:

```
<target name="compilarJar" depends="clean">
<echo message="-------------- Compila Jar --------------"/>
     <javac srcdir="../src/com" destdir="../com" classpathref="classpath" encoding="8859_1" includeantruntime="false">
     <compilerarg arg="-Djava.library.path='C:\\Users\\myUser\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CapturaCamaraWeb2\\lib\\win32-x86\\'" />
     </javac>

</target>
```

tried with absolute and relative paths but none of them work, any help for making my jar work I'll appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed a command line, runtime argument into the compiling.  If you want to hard code a system property, use System.setProperty.  You can modify this to append to the existing library path and/or use a relative path to make it more portable.

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\Users\\myUser\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CapturaCamaraWeb2\\lib\\win32-x86\\" );
Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```

Comment: `java.library.path` is a readonly property and cannot be changed that way. For a workaround see this blog: http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/